# Safely Passing AJAX Values To PHP

Tags: php, ajax, validation, security

I am making a website that allows a user to sign in via google and I need to be able to send the name, email, and user image url to the server. I am currently using AJAX to do this. Below is the function that I use :

```
function onSignIn(googleUser){
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('php').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('POST', "google_sign_in.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send('name=' + profile.getName() + '&image=' + profile.getImageUrl() + '&email=' + profile.getEmail());
}
```

This sends all of the information to the server. There is nothing preventing a user from using a web inspecting tool such as Firebug to change the values within the `xhttp.send` function to something like :

```
xhttp.send(name=fakename&imagefakeimg.jpg&email=fake@information.com);
```

I did some reading and have concluded that I should never rely client side security (trying to block web inspectors) and should go with more server side validation.

I have access HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP. How could I keep users from entering invalid information?

note: I am willing to learn other ways of sending client side information to the server if that is what it takes. Also, I do not have access to a command line.

Comment: I think if you use the google supplied oauth login API you can grab the data directly from the google servers

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript as you made, but only sends Google token to you php script.

FYI, token is here: googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

In you php script, use Google php API client library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

And verify the token, retrieve user infos & save it in your DB.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!